# Grafana: Using MySQL table column of type string as X-Axis for graph

Tags: mysql, grafana

My MySQL datasource for Grafana has a table with semver column of type string (“x.y.z”) and a metric. I want to plot it as a graph with product semantic versions on X-Axis and actual metric value on Y-Axis. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Grafana is designated for timeseries. So first generate fake time series for each product semantic versions - add `time` field (e.g. use current time for `time` field) and then switch `X-Axis` mode to `Series`.